# Can't locate object method via package subclassing DBI

Tags: perl, oop, subclass, dbi

this is my first foray into subclassing with perl and I am wondering why I am getting this simple error...
"Can't locate object method "prepare" via package "WebDB::st" at /home/dblibs/WebDB.pm line 19.". It seems to find the module WebDB ok, but not the prepare subroutine in ::st
First here's my package (both packages are in one file, WebDB.pm)

```
package WebDB;
use strict;
use DBI;

sub connect {
    my $dbh = (DBI->connect ("DBI:mysql:test:127.0.0.1", "root","",
                    { PrintError => 1, RaiseError => 0 }));
    return bless $dbh, 'WebDB::st';
}

package WebDB::st;
our @ISA = qw(::st);
sub prepare {
    my ($self, $str, @args) = @_;
    $self->SUPER::prepare("/* userid:$ENV{USER} */ $str", @args);
}


1;
```

I also tried replacing the "our @ISA = qw(;;st)" with "use base 'WebDB'" and same problem.
I'm thinking it's probably something very simple that I'm overlooking. Many thanks! Jane

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Subclassing DBI has to be done just right to work correctly.  Read [Subclassing the DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI#Subclassing_the_DBI) carefully and properly set RootClass (or explicitly call connect on your root class with @ISA set to DBI).  Make sure you have WebDB::st subclassing DBI::st and a WebDB::db class subclassing DBI::db (even if there are no methods being overridden).  No need to rebless.

Avoid using `base`; it has some unfortunate behavior that has led to its deprecation, particularly when used with classes that are not in a file of their own.
Either explicitly set @ISA or use the newer `parent` pragma:

```
package WebDB;
use parent 'DBI';
...
package WebDB::db;
use parent -norequire => 'DBI::db';
...
package WebDB::st;
use parent -norequire => 'DBI::st';
...
```

Comment: ysth! You rock! This worked great! I am editing some others code (who unfortunately left our company) and I am 
a. happy for this answer and b. happy to dig more into subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

Are `WebDB` and `WebDB::st` in one file or two? If they are in separate files, I don't see anything that is doing a `use WebDB::st;`, which would cause that file to be loaded.

You can do either of these things as a remedy -- put the two packages in the same file (that would look exactly as you have pasted it above), or add a `use WebDB::st;` line in WebDB.pm.

(I'd also add `use strict; use warnings;` in both these packages too.)

Also, the prepare function is *not* in `::st` -- there is no such package (unless it is defined elsewhere). `prepare` is in the `WebDB::st` namespace -- via the `package` declaration. You are however declaring that `WebDB::st` has `::st` as a parent.

Comment: Thanks Ether. These are in the same file. I'll edit that in. JW

Answer (score 0):

If subclassing is as tricky as ysth seems to think, I might recommend [`Class::Delegator`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aDelegator) from CPAN. I use if for classes that want to act like `IO`. And by it, Perl is the first language (that I am aware of) that has an expression language for aggregation, delegation, encapsulation almost equal with inheritance.

```
package WebDB;
use strict;
use DBI;

use Class::Delegator
    send => [ qw<connect ...> ]
  , to   => '{_dbihandle}'
    ...
  ;
```

Comment: it's only tricky because DBI tries to do some of the work for you and multiple classes are involved.